# Is there a search engine with an API and python implament

Tags: python, search, search-engine

i'm looking for a good search engine API for a project, a simple one that i can send a query and get a result set via API.

Google, bing, yahoo all seemed to stop providing with these kind of service and Faroo requires me to have an actual website.

thanks

Comment: All you cited offer you that, just gotta "have your key".

Answer (score 0):

You can look into duckduckgo. Although not a complete API but [this](https://duckduckgo.com/api) may serve partially the purpose.

Search engines are very large, complex and involved systems. The [most valuable brand](http://fortune.com/2017/02/02/google-tops-apple-brand-value/) on this planet is a search engine giant. I am not surprised that this data is not readily available for people to consume and build their own apps.

And I also think Bing also gives you search results via [APIs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-web-search-api/). I personally used it and it works perfectly fine.

I am not sure any of them has a official Python client(duckduckgo seems to have [a community one](https://github.com/crazedpsyc/python-duckduckgo)). But with a little bit of work you can build one easily.